# Can't access res/drawable in xml file

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-animation, xml-drawable

I am creating a loading screen using animation-list but I've run into a error where I cannot get access to my res/drawable folders inside my xml file. The error I get is "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/loadingwave0.png')"

Inside the directory res/anim/ My xml code is simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:oneshot="false" >  
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/loadingwave0.png"
        android:duration="100" />    
</animation-list>
```

I've noticed that inside my item tag, Eclipse does not predict any drawable resources even though I've already copied them(not referenced) to the drawable folders(hdpi, ldpi, mdpi). My .png images **can** be accessed through my AndroidManifest.xml file if I use the code

```
<item android:icon="@drawable/loadingwave0.png"/>
```

for making sure the drawable folders can be accessed. I have already cleaned and refreshed my project multiple times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have drawable folder??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:oneshot="false" >  
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/loadingwave0"
        android:duration="100" />    
</animation-list>
```

the resource id is the file name without extension.